# Deploying Entire Project getting "Cannot create workflow directly" Related to Reply and Question Sobjects

Tags: workflow, deployment, sobject

I'm using Sublime with Mavensmate to deploy an existing project to my SF dev org. Upon deploying I get the following errors.

```
Reply.workflow: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
Question.workflow: Cannot create workflow directly; must create the CustomObject first
```

I don't see Reply or Question sobjects in my org, how can I enable these objects so my deployment runs successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to enable **Chatter Answers**, the steps I took are as follows:

1. From within SF org go to **Setup** navigate to **Customize** -> **Chatter Answers** ->
   **Chatter Answers Settings** (or search **Chatter Answers Settings**)
2. Click **Edit** button
3. Check the field **Enable Chatter Answers** (as well
   as any other additional features/options you'd like to enable)
4. Click the **Save** button

**Reply** and **Question** sobjects should now appear in **Setup** under **Customize** -> **Chatter Answers**. The related workflows started deploying successfully after this.